# Jquery открытие не более одного попапа одновременно

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть примитивный пример, где открываются окошки при клике на кнопку. Вопрос, как сделать, чтоб одновременно 2 окошка или более нельзя было открыть. То есть если одно открыто, то при открытие второго, чтоб первое закрывалось. Спасибо
https://jsfiddle.net/e043pLzd/15/

```js
$('.btn-opener').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".container-item").toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.container-item {
  position: relative;
}
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container-item.active .popup {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;  
}

.btn-opener {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-item">
    <div class="btn-opener">Я кнопка</div>
    <div class="popup">я всплывающая тучка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-item">
    <div class="btn-opener">Я кнопка 2</div>
    <div class="popup">я всплывающая тучка 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-item">
    <div class="btn-opener">Я кнопка 3</div>
    <div class="popup">я всплывающая тучка 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это же очевидно, по клику закрыть все, потом открыть одно, то что должно быть открыто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const containerItem = $(".container-item");
$('.btn-opener').click(function() {
  let currentItem = $(this).closest(".container-item");
  containerItem.not(currentItem).removeClass('active');
  currentItem.toggleClass('active');
});
```

**UPD** Оптимальней даже так:

```
const containerItem = $(".container-item");
$('.btn-opener').click(function() {
  let currentItem = containerItem.has(this);
  containerItem.not(currentItem).removeClass('active');
  currentItem.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Единожды кешируем все элементы `.container-item` и просто отфильтровываем по мере надобности.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn-opener').click(function() {
  var wasOpen = $(this).closest(".container-item").hasClass('active');
  $(".container-item.active").removeClass('active');
  if (!wasOpen)
    $(this).closest(".container-item").addClass('active');
});
```